# A question related almost everywhere convergence in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$ and the the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then by compact embedding we have  $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ (upto a subsequence). Also we have $\{|\nabla u_n|\}_n$ is bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$. So it implies that upto a subsequence $\nabla u_n$ is weakly convergent.

Now the question that is it true that upto a subsequence $\nabla u_n\rightarrow \nabla u$ alomost everywhere?.

Comment: You only get weak convergence $\nabla u_n \rightharpoonup \nabla u$ in $L^p(\Omega)^n$. This is not enough to deduce pointwise a.e. convergence.

Comment: In the first $u_n \to u$ you want $L^{p*}$ with $p* = pn/(n - p)$, right?

Comment: Adrian, yes right